# custom date range of datepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the datepicker pluging and implementing a custom range. I have included all the associated files, I mean jquery js file, date-picker/date.js, date-picker/daterangepicker.js.

When I mouse over the start calendar month and end calendar month, the date is changing and showing in the default area, but the dates I have chosen as start date and end date are not changing ultimately. In JS console, it is showing `TypeError: this.leftCalendar.calendar[row] is undefined`.

In the daterangepicker.js (which is downloaded and kept the same as the original), I have tried to debug.

```
clickDate: function (e) {
 //alert(e);
 var title = $(e.target).attr('title');
 var row = title.substr(1, 1);
 var col = title.substr(3, 1);
 var cal = $(e.target).parents('.calendar');
 //  alert(row);
 if (cal.hasClass('left')) {
    startDate = this.leftCalendar.calendar[row][col];
    // alert(startDate);
    endDate = this.endDate;
    if (typeof this.dateLimit == 'object') {
      var maxDate = new Date(startDate).add(this.dateLimit);
      if (endDate.isAfter(maxDate)) {
          endDate = maxDate;
      }
    }
    this.element.trigger('clicked', {
        dir: 'left',
        picker: this
    });
  }
  ........
  ........
```

If I try to print the value of `e` first then `row` then it is shows the proper values for both. But if I print the value of `row` first then it is now showing. It is printing blank in the alert box and in js console it is showing the `TypeError: this.leftCalendar.calendar[row] is undefined`.

Please suggest to me what the issue is.

UPDATED

if I try to print the `startDate` then it is showing the following error(obviously alert(e) is anabled):

```
Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.alert]
Source File: http://localhost/../js/date-picker/daterangepicker.js
Line: 456
```

in line no 456, I am just printing `alert(startDate);`.

Comment: What is the value of `title`?

Comment: if alert(e) is enabled then alert(title) showing a string that is the combination of rows and columns position e.g r2c3

Comment: for a kind information if alert(e) is enabled then everything is proper.

Comment: anybody is there to help?

Comment: I got the solution. This is only happening for tooltip.

Comment: @Mausumi Can you create a jsfiddle?